# Perfect matching decomposition algorithm for bipartite regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

It is a well-known result that a bipartite graph can be decomposed into edge-disjoint perfect matchings if and only if it is regular. Now here comes the question. Given a bipartite regular graph, is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find such a decomposition into edge-disjoint perfect matchings? If this bipartite regular graph is also vertex-transitive, is it easier to find such a decomposition?

Comment: The standard proof of the result already gives a simple polynomial-time algorithm: find a perfect matching, remove it from the graph (which preserves its being regular bipartite), rinse and repeat until the graph is empty. I don’t know if there is anything more efficient.

Comment: If the graph is $d$ Regular for $d$ Power of 2, then there is a nice linear time algorithm (O($m$)) time

Comment: Specifically, find an Eulerian cycle and remove m/2 edges from B to A. You get a d/2 regular graph with m/2 edges. Repeat recursively until you have your matching

Comment: @AspiringMat Good idea. You can use it even if $d$ is not a power of $2$: if $d$ is even, find an Eulerian cycle as you describe, halving the degree; if $d$ is odd, find and remove a perfect matching first, making $d$ even. Then repeat.

Comment: But note that even in the power of 2 case, you need to recursively process *both* halves of the graph to get a decomposition. Thus, this will be time $O(m\log m)$ rather than $O(m)$. This time bound holds for general $d$ as well (finding perfect matchings in regular bipartite graphs can be done in time $O(m)$).

Comment: I meant $O(m\log d)$, not $O(m\log m)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, my initial comment was on just a single matching, but for the entire decomposition, you get an extra log factor in there as you mention, thanks for adding.